# Get IdentifyingNumber of Software in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmic

I need the IdentifyingNumber of a certain Software as in ONLY the IdentifyingNumber.

Here is my code which finds the ID of a certain Software.

```
$k_agent_identifyingnumber = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*XY* *XY* *XY*"} | Select IdentifyingNumber

Write-Host $k_agent_identifyingnumber
```

Which gives me the result

```
@{IdentifyingNumber={XXXF24-88AB-45E1-A6E6-40C8278XXXX}}
```

Is it possible to remove the whole "@{IdentifyingNumber=} ???

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The most common question in powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the property, to only return the property value.

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber
```

Comment: This. There is also good information on the [`Select-Object` cmdlet at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6).